# Captive portal Nodogsplash

Tags: android, router, captiveportal

I have installed TP-Link WR1043ND and set up a Captive portal using Nodogsplash. So my goal is that when clients connect to my wifi using a mobile device they press on either the Apple Store icon or the Google Playstore so that it redirects them on the page to download the app. It works great and no problem with the Apple Store but when it comes to android it actually opens the playstore and then closes the window right away.

I have done a research, alot of people are complaining about the android that it force shutdowns the Playstore but i cant seem to find a workaround or a way to get my problem solved.

I just want the user to press on the google playstore image and that it redirects it to the app page and stays there instead of force closing it automatically. So that the client can press "install" on my app.

```
<form method='GET' action='$authaction' target='_blank'>
    <input type='hidden' name='tok' value='$tok'>
    <input type='hidden' name='redir' value='https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps&hl=en'> 
    <input class='btn-os' type='image' src='$imagesdir/GooglePlay_Logo.png'>
</form>

<form method='GET' action='$authaction' target='_blank'> 
    <input type='hidden' name='tok' value='$tok'>
    <input type='hidden' name='redir' value='https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-maps-navigation-transit/id585027354?mt=8'>  
    <input class='btn-os' type='image' src='$imagesdir/AppStore_Logo.png'>
</form><br>
```

That piece of code is what appears on my captive portal and when you click it will send you to google maps(used as example in this case)